# Files.write() is not working properly, while BufferedWriter seems to be fine

Tags: java, file, file-io

I had a simple exercise to do:

- read a file
- filter out all lines beginning with "//"
- remove additional spaces
- write it back to a file

And I came up with following code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static java.nio.file.Files.lines;
import static java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter;
import static java.nio.file.Files.write;
import static java.nio.file.Paths.get;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class FileParser {
    public static final String PATH = "test.txt";

    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            List<String> strings = lines(get(PATH)).filter(line -> !line.startsWith("//")).map(line -> line.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ")).collect(toList());
//            write(get(PATH), strings, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
            BufferedWriter writer = newBufferedWriter(get(PATH));
            for (String string : strings) {
                writer.write(string);
                writer.newLine();
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately that commented piece of code for some reason doesn't work, while the one below it works just fine. That strings list always contains only proper result too. For file:

```
a
//b
c
```

The expected result should be:

```
a
c
```

While the actual result is:

```
a
c

c
```

What is the source of this problem?

It works when writing to a different file that the one we read from it.

Comment: Using static imports the way you did just makes the code harder to read.  Don't do it.

Comment: You may also want to use `StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html) the Javadoc for `StandardOpenOptions`. This is what it says about `WRITE` option:

> Open for write access.

Although it's not too informative, it opens the file and starts writing from the beginning. It overwrites the existing content and keep remaining text as is. If you want to remove the existing content then you need to use `TRUNCATE_EXISTING` option:

> If the file already exists and it is opened for WRITE access, then its length is truncated to 0. This option is ignored if the file is opened only for READ access.

You need to make sure the file is not open (in any editor or in program) before using this option.

Here is the test program that works fine with your file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> strings = Files.lines(Paths.get("<somepath>/Test.txt")).filter(line -> !line.startsWith("//")).map(line -> line.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(strings);
    Files.write(Paths.get("<somepath>/Test.txt"), strings, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
}
```

Comment: It does, I have added the test program that works with sample file provided in question.